# What is this java applet code missing?

Tags: java, swing

Below is a simple Java form using Java Swing. It is supposed to create the applet and show a simple form, but neither the form nor any errors arise. I do not know exactly what is missing in this.

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class front extends JApplet implements ActionListener{

// Labels
JLabel lblName = new JLabel();
JLabel lblCountry = new JLabel();
JLabel lblDesc = new JLabel();

// Text Fields
JTextField txtName = new JTextField();
JTextField txtCountry = new JTextField();
JTextField txtDesc = new JTextField();

// Save and cancel buttons
JButton save = new JButton("Save");
JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");

// The main window (frame)
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Author Registeration");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

public void init(){

    //frame.add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel.add(lblName);
    panel.add(txtName);
    panel.add(lblCountry);
    panel.add(txtCountry);
    panel.add(lblDesc);
    panel.add(txtDesc);
    panel.add(cancel);
    panel.add(save);
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    //frame.SetDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

}

//@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}
}
```

Comment: How are you running it...?

Comment: I have written and ran it in eclipse

Comment: Does `Applet Viewer` come up?

Comment: Did you run it as 'Java Applet'?

Comment: Oh my god! I tested it now! I ran it as java applet and it was shown well! thanks!

Comment: I think the probelm is the inclusion of the `main` method...

Answer (score 0):

what you want **Applet Window(JApplet)** or **System Window(JFrame)**
if you want Applet no need main function. ***init*** can handle startup.
if you want JFrame no need to extend JApplet Class.
JFrame and JApplet is two different concepts.

try applet with this

```
public class front extends JApplet implements ActionListener{

// Labels
JLabel lblName = new JLabel();
JLabel lblCountry = new JLabel();
JLabel lblDesc = new JLabel();

// Text Fields
JTextField txtName = new JTextField();
JTextField txtCountry = new JTextField();
JTextField txtDesc = new JTextField();

// Save and cancel buttons
JButton save = new JButton("Save");
JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");


JPanel panel = new JPanel();

public void init(){

    setSize(500,500);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setVisible(true);
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel.add(lblName);
    panel.add(txtName);
    panel.add(lblCountry);
    panel.add(txtCountry);
    panel.add(lblDesc);
    panel.add(txtDesc);
    panel.add(cancel);
    panel.add(save);
    add(panel);

}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}
}
```

Comment: It's possible to use `JFrame` with `JApplet` to create a separate window.

Comment: if you run in eclipse it's possible, your jframe will show. but applet basically run in browsers. if you run in browsers the jframe not come to your browser.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (What I had missed about the the IDE) is easily solved by running the code as ***Java Applet*** which is necessary if your Java program is structured as an applet!